# When to use parallel programming in R to apply a function to each row

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr, doparallel

There are many ways to apply a function to each row.

Here some methods that I know:

**method 1**

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data) ) { my_function(data[i,]) }
```

**method 2**

```
apply(data,1,my_function)
```

**method 3**

```
library(plyr)
adply(data,.margins=1, .fun=my_function)
```

**method 4**

```
library(doParallel)
nodes <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(nodes)
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterEvalQ(cl,source("my_fun.R"))
adply(data,.margins=1, .parallel = T, .fun=my_function)
stopCluster(cl)
```

among the top 3 methods, I think the faster is the third one. But the question is: when method 4 (the parallel one) is faster than method 3? there is a way to understand it before to run all the code?

Comment: Test if `my_function(data[1,])` takes a significant amount of time. In such a case parallelization can really help performance (assuming you can't improve the function or avoid an R level loop altogether).

Comment: In general, don't use apply on a data frame. It tends to do Bad Things.